# How can use json data bind in datatable and grivdview in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

I am parsing JSON Data in custom gridview and I get the following error:

I am using the Newtonsoft.Json.NET dll.

Additional information: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

I am using this code

```
var result = _profitGenDiagnosticsService.GetSQLQueryResult(profitGenQueryEditorModel.SqlQuery);
var o = JObject.Parse(result);
DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(o.ToString());
profitGenQueryEditorModel.SqlQueryResult = dt;

return PartialView("_ProfitGenQueryResult", profitGenQueryEditorModel);
```

Comment: please give me solution

Comment: {"Table":[{"Books_ID":1,"Books_Name":"Executive","Books_UserID":null,"Books_IsStandard":true,"Books_CreatedDate":"2016-01-18T12:15:27.617","Books_ModifiedDate":"2016-01-18T12:15:27.617"}]}  I get this type of data How can i use in datatable